# Doctrine ORM: How to define a 1-n realtionship with a n-n connecting table

Tags: doctrine

So, this is a bit complicated: I have two tables, say `cats` and `dogs`. 
They are in a many-to-many relationship (could be called `friendships` or whatever), so that Doctrine automatically creates a table `cats_dogs` for me with the appropriate fields. (that is `rowid, cat_id, dog_id` per default.)

Now, imagine I have a third table, `award`, where I want to award one of these friendships. Here I therefore need a field that references one row in `cats_dogs`. However, since this table does not really exist between my models, (Doctrine handles it for me) what would be the most elegant solution for this?

In the end, I want in my `award` model two fields, a `cat` and a `dog`, who need to be in a friendship.

I am using the annotation driver.

Comment: See, this is one of the problems with one-size-fits-all ORMs - something that's trivial and perfectly obvious in SQL itself becomes utterly hard and confusing as soon as an ORM is involved. Sorry for interrupting, carry on.

Comment: I guess it should be possible using Doctrine, without any dirty workarounds... I just don't know how. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What stops you from manually creating the m:n table instead of having doctrine do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

The Doctrine aims is to map objects from an E/R schema and to make easier the access to object connections. Therefore I believe that the table `cats_dogs` automatically provided by Doctrine is necessary as it is. It is concise and hits its purposes, i.e. it provides a list of all dogs of a cat or, vice versa, all the cats of a dog.

Thus, I can conclude that it is preferable to create a third entity (besides `Cat` and `Dog`) named `Award` which provides a one-to-one relationship with `Cat` and another one-to-one relationship with `Dog`. Making it consistent with the `cats_dogs` table is only up to you, and is not a Doctrine task by default. E.g., you can use some cascade persist option. 
I believe that this is the most effective solution with Doctrine.

As a final remark, consider that each table should map a specific relationship between one or more entities, and in fact the table `cats_dogs` represents the *friendship* relationships, while the table `Award` will represent the *awarded relationship* relationship between two friends.